# javascript game how should I reduce the coupling of an entity from the main window?

Tags: javascript

I have an entity in a game which has an update method, it needs to target the closest zombie, currently the list of zombies is just a global object which I access but this seems wrong, I could pass the list into the update method but I'm not sure if this is the best approach?

here is a simplified version of my update method:

```
this.update = function () {
                var targetedZombie = null;
                //TODO: should not be using the zombies object - tight coupling should be removed
                var alivezombies = [];
                for (var zombie in zombies) {
                    if (zombies[zombie].Alive) {
                        alivezombies.push(zombies[zombie]);
                    }
                }

                targetedZombie = this.GetClosestEntity(alivezombies);
                if (targetedZombie) {
                    Fire(this, targetedZombie);
                }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use closures
//init your api

```
    (function(global) {
      var zombies = []; // accessible only to you

      function zombieManager() { 
         this.addZombie = function() {  zombies.push() }
         this.killHalfZombies = function() { 
                  zombies = zombies.filter(function(item,i) { return i % 2 == 0});
         }
      }
      global.zombieManager = new zombieManager();

      function hero() {

      };

      hero.prototype.update = function() {
        //dig zombies[]
        //do whatever state change
      };
      global.hero = hero;
    })(window); //<-- you pass in whatever rootlevel object we have. window in a browser.

//use api
    var myhero = new hero();
    hero.update() //<-- this can access zombies

    zombieManager.addZombie(); //<-- zombieManager is a singleton and is responsible for zombification
```

Comment: Useful Idea of using the singleton, although this is still exposing the zombies array to the whole API, the api will effectively be the whole game unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Shouldn't zombies be available to the whole API/game of yours. Above example shows how to not couple one of your main data to a publicly writable window property.

Answer (score 1):

Some good resources on game architecture to get you started is ["Good resources for learning about game architecture"?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/455/good-resources-for-learning-about-game-architecture) on gamedev. Generally a good practice is breaking the components of game into single concepts. In this simple scenario I would make the list of zombies a component on the Game class and have a method on it FindClosest(PositionOfHero). The window would initiate the correct object graph only, not persisting links between the graph as global arrays.

Comment: thanks for the link, I think I've already got a reasonable grasp of the basic concepts, having zombies as a component still means the hero needs to have an instance of the component as a global object(not much difference between a component wrapping an array and just exposing the array itself?)